# ASP.Net element/page positioning basics

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an ASP.net 4 app with a bunch of pages, all using the Site.Master as the primary layout which is a colored background, border, menu at the top and a gif in the bottom right corner of the border.

I've positioned everything using position:absolute and just set all of the elements in the site.master and the individual elements that appear on each page by using style:"left:100px top 100px" etc

So when you launch the app in normal IE mode everything looks perfect, however if you go full screen or you minimize IE, everything goes completely out of shape and all over the place.

What do I need to do in order for it to be consistent no matter whether you're in normal IE/Full screen/Minimized? Do I need to change the way I have used style:position tags on all of the elements or is it something else that I need to do?

Comment: what you need to do, is post the relevant code in your question because we have no idea what you are talking about otherwise.

Comment: Just slap a note on it: _"This page is best viewed on 1024x768"_. In all seriousness, it sounds like you should start over, preferably after reading some tutorials on HTML/CSS and website design in general.

Comment: :) CodeCaster - It's only really the image and the user controls which I've positioned that are going crazy when you change into full screen etc. What should I be searching for in tutorials - HTML page positioning? CSS page positioning?

Answer (score 0):

Page is not holding your settings because the width off page changes when you change browser size.

To make things all the same no mater what is the size of browser window set this with off body element.

Something like this:

```
<body style="width:1024px">
```

Comment: Something like what Cezary? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry don't know why it didn't paste last time, just add width to body element: <body style="width:1024px"> maybe you will have to set correct width for your page

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to put a 
    div style="position:relative;" 
inside and at the start of the BodyContent of each page then use absolute positioning on each of the elements which keeps all of them within the BodyContent border and shifts them properly when the browser is minimized or full-screened. Is this a good approach? It seems to have solved the problem I had but I'm concerned it may cause more problems I'm not currently aware of?